# Rewriting a formula (hopefully just basic algebra..)

Tags: abstract-algebra, transformation

I have a question which actually involves statistics, but I think it comes down to some basic algebra, so hopefully someone here can help me out (as I am obviously not a mathematician).

Let’s say I have a formula in the following form:

```
                        A = (B/C)(D-E) or A=(4/2)(D-3),
```

as A and D can vary and B,C and E are actually fixed values. From this I want to rewrite the right-hand side of the formula so that I end up with D in a form were I multiply it with B (or B/C), without having to subtract something from D or divide it first. So something like:

```
                        A = (B/C)(D)-.... or A=(4/2)(D)-....
```

However, I have been struggling in finding out how to do this, so I hope someone can provide me a solution for this.

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can separate $A,C,E$ from $B,D$ in $A={B\over C(D-E)}$. I don't understand what the second formula is doing.

Comment: On the other hand, if you mean $A={B\over C(D-E)}$ AND $A={4\over2(D-3)}$, then you can get somewhere; solve the second equation for $D$, plug what you get into the 1st equation, and isolate $B$, and you're done.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for your answer. Sorry for not clearly formulating my question. What I actually wanted was to rewrite the right-hand side of the formula like this: `B/C*(D-E) = (B/C*D)-(E*B/C)` or `4/2*(D-3) = (4/2*D)-(3*4/2)`, but as you can see I just found out how to do this.

Comment: Your notation is very unclear. $B/C^*D$ could mean $B/(CD)$ or it could mean $(B/C)D$. Anyway, if you have figured out how to solve your problem, you should write up and post a solution (and then, some hours later, you can accept it).

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks. I just edited my question and changed the notation, so hope it is more clear now, otherwise please correct me. My reputation is too low to answer the question within 8 hours so will do that later: `(B/C)(D-E) = (B/C)D-E(B/C)`